# Reputation display inconsistencies?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm seeing some strangeness with the display of reputation gained today. In some places it's showing as 230 and in others it's showing as 228. I've added up everything visible on my profile for today and this equates to 230. I've done a reputation recalculation on /reputation but the numbers are still showing the same after leaving it for an hour or so.

The numbers are as follows;

The new top bar reputation drop down is showing 230:

[image]

The reputation list on my profile is showing 230:

[image]

The reputation graph on my profile page shows 228:

[image]

What is my actual reputation gain for today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your profile's reptuation tab.  If you click it, you'll see that the numbers match up.  It's [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93217/equipping-the-heroic-and-non-heroic-version-of-the-same-trinket-at-once/93218#93218) that you're not seeing.